# docker-compose is giving the error: backend exited with code 2 backend | /bin/sh: syntax error: unterminated quoted string

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, e-commerce, mern

I am stuck in building the docker containers for MERN stack E-commerce app. These are my following Docker files and Docker compose files. I am getting this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkzEh.png)

```js
# Dockerfile for React client

# Build react client
FROM node:lts-buster-slim

# Working directory be app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app
COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app

###  Installing dependencies

RUN npm ci

# copy local files to app folder
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

```js
#  Dockerfile for Node Express Backend

FROM node:lts-buster-slim

# Create App Directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install Dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app/package-lock.json
RUN npm ci

COPY . /usr/src/app

# Exports
EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

```js
version: "3.7"
services:
  frontend:
    build: frontend
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    container_name: frontend
    restart: always
    networks:
      - react-express
    depends_on:
      - backend

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    restart: always
    build: backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    networks:
      - express-mongo
      - react-express
    ports: 
      - 5000:5000
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    restart: always
    image: mongo:4.2.0
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    networks:
      - express-mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
networks:
  react-express:
  express-mongo:
```

I am getting this error when I execute the command: "docker-compose up". I am doing a MERN E-Commerce App. The error is: backend     | /bin/sh: syntax error: unterminated quoted string
backend exited with code 2

Comment: What is your `npm run dev` command in `backend`? Could you add it as specified in `package.json`?

Comment: My package.json file has the following scripts:           ` code` "scripts": {
    "start": "node backend/server",
    "server": "nodemon backend/server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix frontend",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",} ` code`           And I am using concurrently

Comment: Does `npm run dev` works for you in local?

Comment: Yeah. It is working on my wsl2 localhost server.

Comment: In the `CMD` in the Dockerfile, can you double-check that you have ordinary ASCII "straight" quotes?  You could also try `docker inspect directoryname_backend` to see what's in the image and in particular how its `CMD` got interpreted.

Comment: Can you please provide the exact command in double quotes? I am not getting what commands you are referring to?

Comment: Replace “directoryname” text in David Maze’s command with the name of the folder you are keeping the backend project. Then run it in the terminal. You will get a big JSON output in the terminal. There search for “Cmd” and you will see which command arguments are actually executed in the container.

Comment: **docker inspect proshopu_backend** ; I am getting the error: `Error: No such object: ProShopU_backend`

Comment: Change last line of your backend Dockerfile to `CMD ["sleep", "forever"]` and then run the docker-compose up command. Then in your terminal type `docker exec -it ProShopU_backend /bin/sh`. This will open up a terminal inside the container. Try to run `npm run dev` and see what happens?

Comment: I did `docker-compose up`. But, I am getting the same error and it is an infinite loop I think. It is showing the error message `backend     | /bin/sh: syntax error: unterminated quoted string` continuously and it is not giving any access to the container terminal. If I stop, it exits out of the docker.

Comment: Did you replace this “CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]” with the command I put in my earlier comment?

Comment: Yeah I did it: `CMD ["sleep", "forever"]` in place of `CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]`

Comment: In your terminal execute `docker-compose down` and then try again to do the same thing you I asked earlier

Comment: I am getting the same error even after doing this?

Comment: Okay, type `docker system prune` and remove all the docker related cache from your machine. Then try to restart your machine and run `docker-compose up` again. (While having `CMD ["sleep", "forever"]`). Ideally, it should work. Then try to redo the above step I asked.

Comment: No bro. Again, getting the same error. The Docker dashboard is showing that frontend: running port:3000.   backend: **restarting** port: 5000.   mongo: running port:27017